# preg_replace with pattern and subject array returning empty array

Tags: php, preg-replace, str-replace, array-difference

I want a simple way to delete elements of $badwords from $keywords.

What I have (as an example)

```
$keywords = array('sebastian','nous','helene','lol'); //it could be anything in fact
$badwords = array('nous', 'lol', 'ene', 'seba'); //array full of stop words that I won't write here
$filtered_keywords = array_filter(preg_replace($badwords,'',$keywords), 'strlen');
print_r($filtered_keywords);
```

What I expected

```
Array ( [0] => samaha [1] => helene )
```

What I got

```
 Sweet nothing :)
```

I tried to use `str_ireplace` but it went bad because it was replacing within the strings in my array.

Comment: What is in `$excluded_words`?

Comment: `$excluded_words` should be `$badwords`? or i dint get it?

Comment: Corrected my example but code was ok. Sorry for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `array_diff`

```
var_dump(array_diff($keywords, $badwords));
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(9) "sebastian"
  [2]=>
  string(6) "helene"
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$keywords = array('sebastian','nous','helene','lol');

$badwords = array('nous', 'lol', 'ene', 'seba'); 

$filtered_keywords=array_diff($keywords,$badwords);
```

Answer (score 1):

Incorrect Array name most probably

```
$filtered_keywords = array_filter(preg_replace($excluded_words,'',$keywords), 'strlen');
```

it isnt **$excluded_words**, it is **$badwords**

Answer (score 1):

You're missing a semicolon after

```
$keywords = array('sebastian','nous','helene','lol')
```

[And you can use `array_diff`:](http://ideone.com/xCIbhw)

```
$filtered_keywords = array_diff($keywords, $badwords);
```

Answer (score 0):

You missed the slashes `/` in the $badwords. and you missed the semicolon `;` at the end of the fist line.
Try this code:

```
<?php

$keywords = array('sebastian','nous','helene','lol'); //it could be anything in fact
$badwords = array('/nous/', '/lol/', '/ene/', '/seba/'); //array full of stop words that I won't write here

$filtered_keywords = array_filter(preg_replace($badwords,'',$keywords), 'strlen');

echo print_r($filtered_keywords);

?>
```